# How do apply class to siblings in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay, I have this code:

```
<li>
  <a href="#step-2" class="step-3-link selected">
    <span class="stepNumber">2</span>
  </a>
  <br />
  <br />
  <span class="sn2">Home Page Banner</span>
</li>
```

What I need to do is that if the 'li a' has class selected, which in this case step-3-link does, the span with class 'sn2' should be added a class 'selected-span'.

The code which I'd tried before was as below:

```
$('.swMain ul.anchor li a.selected').siblings('span').addClass('selected-span');
```

I tried .siblings, .find, .parent and what not but with no success. Kindly guide me for the same.

Comment: post the code that you tried

Comment: And where is this code which you have tried to run?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with only CSS 2.1's [general sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) and no JS.

So instead of adding another class called `selected-span`, put the required settings in the following block:

```
.step-3-link.selected ~ span.sn2 {
    /* enter custom settings here */
}
```

---

> ## General sibling selectors
>
> The ~ combinator separates two selectors and matches the second
> element only if it is preceded by the first, and both share a common
> parent.

Comment: You see how easy jQuery has made our life. We neglect simple CSS solutions and head for scripts. So ignorant of me. Thank you Itay, this one worked fine.

Comment: Our company's portal team had a mission lately for refactoring code written with jQuery to normal CSS... A lot of code was thrown to the garbage.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code,

```
if($('a').hasClass('selected')){
     $(this).parent().find('.sn2').addClass('selected-span');
}
```

Comment: this looks fine isn't it?

Comment: Well, you're still missing a dot before the name of the class inside the `find` function. Also maybe this is better `$(this).siblings('.sn2')`

Comment: I did use the above solution but it didn't work. Maybe I might have put the syntax incorrect. Shall try again. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem you are trying to solve correctly, then I would say you may want to add a `selected` class to the clicked `a span` and remove the existing selection

```
$('li a').click(function(){
$('li a span').removeClass('selected');
$(this).find('span').addClass('selected');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[The fiddle =)](http://jsfiddle.net/cAz3B/)

JQUERY :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li').each(function() {
        if($('a.selected').length) {
            $('.sn2', $(this)).addClass('selected-span');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: there is no need to wrap `this` in `$`

Comment: he need the wrap, because he will probably have multiple li

Comment: What ABFORCE is saying is that you can just write `$('.sn2', this)`

Comment: oh OK, i didn't know, thanks for that tip. I think im gonna loving you <3

Comment: Cool, It is advisable in this kind of cases that you update your answer with the improved code

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty near with your usage of the keyword `next()`, instead you can use `nextAll` to traverse to your desired location :

**JS:**

```
if($('li a').hasClass('selected')){
    $('li a').nextAll('span:first').addClass('sn2 selected-span');
}
```

**Working Demo :**  http://jsfiddle.net/9xUk4/2/

**EDIT :** Provided an alternate Solution after Itay expressed the folly of using too much of the `next()` function .

Comment: Using 3 `.next()` calls is way too coupled with the current DOM. What if he will have more `<br />` tags? Use less coupled solutions

Comment: Yes, It might be a lot of overhead , ok i have changed my code to just get the span. Updating the code qbove @Itay

Comment: @Nimsrules Code's updated to reflect exactly what is needed .